# Fuzzy search in PgSQL text array

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

In my `PgSql` table `places` there is a column- `nearby` which is a text array.

Here is `places` table schema

- id: guid
- place: text
- nearby: text[]
- rank: number

I wanted to do the fuzzy search on it. That is, if nearby = {"new york", "boston"}, I should get result when `searchStr` = `bos`.

This is what I'm trying

```sql
SELECT * FROM places
WHERE place ILIKE '%' || :searchStr || '%'
OR '%' || :searchStr || '%' ILIKE any(nearby)
ORDER BY rank DESC
LIMIT 15 OFFSET 0;
```

but it is not returning anything because of `OR '%' || :searchStr || '%' ILIKE any(nearby)`.

Anything I'm missing here?

Comment: The `searchStr` needs to go on the right-hand side of the `ilike` operator.  I cannot think of a way to do this using `any()`.

Comment: You would need to define an operator which reverses the orders of the operands.  Like my answer to https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/228235/match-string-pattern-to-any-array-element/, except for `~~*` not `~~`.